# Modem Bridge WAN Encapsulation and VLAN Tag

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, modem

I have a question, in setting the Modem/Router combo provided by ISP to Bridge WAN instead of Route WAN, does the Frame gets decapsulated (Ethernet Header) and encapsulated again after it passes through the modem? There are encapsulation settings in WAN Configuration, IPoE, and PPPoE.

In Ethernet LAN Switching, when the Frame is being forwarded by the host to the switch, it learns/adds the host MAC address to its table then notes what interface the host came from, then just forwards the Frame without altering the original Frame.

I don't know how the Frames are being altered to the Modem and if it decapsulates and encapsulates again by adding an IPoE/PPP header and a VLAN tag when it sees the Frame.

The type of modem is GPON by the way.

Answers are appreciated.

Comment: What type of modem? Cable (docsis)? ADSL? Vdsl? GPON?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have mentioned it above. It is a GPON Modem.